# Combine data from multiple RDDs using Java

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, rdd

I have 3 CSV files as below, trying to create RDD and combine the RDDs into a final output that I can apply filters on. I am not sure where to get started 
with this. Any suggestions please?

```
JavaRDD<String> file1 = sc.textFile("D:\\tmp\\file1.csv");
JavaRDD<String> file2 = sc.textFile("D:\\tmp\\file2.csv");
JavaRDD<String> file3 = sc.textFile("D:\\tmp\\file3.csv");

JavaRDD<String> combRDD = file1.union(file2).union(file3); //doesn't give expected output
```

csv file1

```
"user","source_ip","action","type"
"abc","10.0.0.1","login","ONE"
"xyz","10.0.1.1","login","ONE"
"abc","10.0.0.1","playing","ONE"
"def","10.1.0.1","login","ONE"
```

csv file2

```
"user","url","type"
"abc","/test","TWO"
"xyz","/wonder","TWO"
```

csv file3

```
"user","total_time","type","status"
"abc","5min","THREE","true"
"xyz","2min","THREE","fail"
```

Final expected output

```
"user","source_ip","action","type","url","total_time","status"
"abc","10.0.0.1","login","ONE","","",""
"xyz","10.0.1.1","login","ONE","","",""
"abc","10.0.0.1","playing","ONE","","",""
"def","10.1.0.1","login","ONE","","",""
"abc","","","TWO","/test","",""
"xyz","","","TWO","/wonder","",""
"abc","","","THREE","","5min","true"
"xyz","","","THREE","","2min","fail"
```

Each of the csv files are generated each day with same format, so I would like to read them from a specific folder with *.csv to build RDD

Answer (score 0):

If you have `SparkSession` object as `spark`

```
spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("file1.csv").join(
  spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("file2.csv"), "user"
).join(
  spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("file3.csv"), "user"
).write.csv("some_output");
```